# JavaScript Number Split into individual digits

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to solve a math problem where I take a number e.g. `45`, or `111` and then split the number into separate digits e.g. `4 5` or `1 1 1`. I will then save each number to a var to run a method on. Does anyone know how to split a number into individual digitals?

For example I have a loop that runs on an array :

```
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
  var n = range[i];
}
```

For each number, I would like to split its digits and add them together?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
var number = 12354987,
    output = [],
    sNumber = number.toString();

for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
}

console.log(output);

/* Outputs:
 *
 * [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7]
 */
```

**UPDATE:** Calculating a sum

```
for (var i = 0, sum = 0; i < output.length; sum += output[i++]);
console.log(sum);

/*
 * Outputs: 39
 */
```

Comment: how easy would it be to then add all the digital together dynamically baring in my the number could be any lenght?

Comment: @jonnyhitek, works fast to me — http://i.imgur.com/TTGZL.png — Chrome 14 @ Win7. And a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lapple/ZmS3B/

Comment: Probably your browser doesn't support the `console` API — change `console` to `alert`.

Comment: no i think its my error i am trying to run your code in my loop -

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4307/discussion-between-jonnyhitek-and-lapple)

Comment: Calculating sum can be more elegantly done with Array.reduce: `var sum = output.reduce((r,v) => r + v, 0);`.

Comment: Or if you like very readable code: `var sum = (x,y) => x+y; var total = output.reduce(sum);`

Answer (score 139):

```js
var num = 123456;
var digits = num.toString().split('');
var realDigits = digits.map(Number)
console.log(realDigits);
```

Comment: add `var realDigits = digits.map(Number)` and we have a deal

Comment: `"555".split('').map(Number)`

Comment: Works great until you have a huge number (eg Math.pow(10,100))

Comment: This breaks with large numbers, like `1e100.toString().split('');` results in `[ "1", "e", "+", "1", "0", "0" ]`.

Answer (score 63):

You can also do it in the "mathematical" way without treating the number as a string:

```js
var num = 278;
var digits = [];
while (num != 0) {
    digits.push(num % 10);
    num = Math.trunc(num / 10);
}
digits.reverse();
console.log(digits);
```

One upside I can see is that you won't have to run `parseInt()` on every digit, you're dealing with the actual digits as numeric values.

Comment: I was trying to solve an algo that would require me to split a number without first  turning it to a string, and this worked on positive numbers but not on negative numbers.  Negative numbers return empty array.

Comment: @Hoxtygen you're correct, for some reason I assumed positive numbers only. I fixed the code, see edit. Essentially, just changed the loop stop condition to stop when it reach zero, while before it also stopped on negative numbers.

Comment: Sweet, this actually works correctly with large numbers, unlike the top answer!

Comment: This hasn't been tested with negative numbers, has it? Returning `[ -2, -7, -8 ]` for `-278` seems like an interesting choice.

Comment: @Stefnotch tested for not empty, which is the "bug" the was "reported" back in December. But you do raise interesting point, while e.g. "-2" isn't strictly a digit, it does help to know the original number was negative. Easy to just ignore number being negative by `Math.abs()` the input, but if you do want to keep that detail something else is needed. So bottom line, can't know in advance the requirement in such cases.

Answer (score 38):

This is the shortest I've found, though it does return the digits as strings:

```
let num = 12345;

[...num+''] //["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Or use this to get back integers:

```
[...num+''].map(n=>+n) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 15):

I will provide a variation on an answer already given so you can see a different approach that preserves the numeric type all along:

```
var number = 12354987,
    output = [];

while (number) {
    output.push(number % 10);
    number = Math.floor(number/10);
}

console.log(output.reverse().join(',')); // 1,2,3,5,4,9,8,7
```

I've used a technique such as the above to good effect when converting a number to Roman numerals, which is one of my favorite ways to begin to learn a programming language I'm not familiar with.  For instance here is how I devised a way to convert numbers to Roman numerals with Tcl slightly after the turn of the century: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/68379-conversion-to-roman-numerals/

The comparable lines in my Tcl script being:

```
  while {$arabic} {
    set digit [expr {$arabic%10}]
    set arabic [expr {$arabic/10}]
```

Comment: This is sad that first decent use of % operator is so low in answers list

Comment: Thanks for the continued up-votes, but in light of ES5 and/or ES6, this answer is hardly valid anymore.  Even as it stands I should have specified `output.unshift` (instead of `push`) thereby making the `reverse()` unnecessary -- a lot people fail to thing of `unshift`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty, thanks for emphasizing ***preservation of the numeric type***.  I spent too much time yesterday unraveling a base conversion problem caused by string input.  I would appreciate any updates to this answer you might have related to ES5/ES6 and/or `output.unshift`.

Answer (score 11):

```js
// Split positive integer n < 1e21 into digits:
function digits(n) {
  return Array.from(String(n), Number);
}

// Example:
console.log(digits(1234)); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `String`, `split` and `map` :

```
String(number).split("").map(Number);
```

```js
function splitNum(num) {
    return String(num).split("").map(Number);
}

console.log(splitNum(1523)); // [1, 5, 2, 3]
console.log(splitNum(2341)); // [2, 3, 4, 1]
console.log(splitNum(325)); // [3, 2, 5]
```

Comment: String removes the zeros though. Is there a way to make it so the zeros don't get removed?

Comment: Do you mean the zeros after the number? Because those don't get rid of them. If you mean the 0 before the number, how does a variable have a zero before the number? For example 001234 is already a string not an integer

Answer (score 5):

You can work on strings instead of numbers to achieve this. You can do it like this

```
(111 + '').split('')
```

This will return an array of strings `['1','1','1']` on which you can iterate upon and call `parseInt` method.

```
parseInt('1') === 1
```

If you want the sum of individual digits, you can use the reduce function (implemented from Javascript 1.8) like this

```
(111 + '').split('').reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){  
  return parseInt(previousValue,10) + parseInt(currentValue,10);  
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Without converting to string:

```
function toDigits(number) {
    var left;
    var results = [];

    while (true) {
        left = number % 10;
        results.unshift(left);
        number = (number - left) / 10;
        if (number === 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `String`, `...` and `map`

```js
const num = 7890;

const digits = [...String(num)].map(Number);

console.log(digits)
```

Alternatively, using `...` and `reduce` to get digits and their sum.

```js
const sumOfDigits = num => [...""+num].reduce((acc, dig) => acc + +dig, 0);

console.log('Sum of digits: ', sumOfDigits(7890));
```

Answer (score 3):

A fun introduction to recursion. This answer takes a Number and returns an array of Number digits. It does *not* convert the number to a string as an intermediate step.

Given `n = 1234`,

- `n % 10` will return first (right-moist) digit, `4`
- `n / 10` will return `123` with some remainder
- Using `Math.floor` we can chop the remainder off
- Repeating these steps, we can form the entire result

Now we just have to build the recursion condition,

- If the number is already a single digit (n < 10), return an array singleton of the digit
- otherwise (inductive) the number is 10 or greater; recur and prepend to the first digit

```js
const digits = (n = 0) =>
  n < 10
    ? [ n ]
    : [ ... digits (Math.floor (n / 10)), n % 10 ]

console.log (digits ())        // [ 0 ]
console.log (digits (1))       // [ 1 ]
console.log (digits (12))      // [ 1, 2 ]
console.log (digits (123))     // [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log (digits (11234))   // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

console.log (digits (123456789012))
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2 ]
```

Comment: This is really neat, but it does not seem to work in every case. `digits(123456789012)` returns `[-539222987, 2]`

Comment: @Wondercricket thanks for catching that, I made an update to fix it. That's a behavior of `>>` I don't quite understand. I wonder if it's a bug?

Comment: *off-topic:* looking forward to see an answer from you on https://stackoverflow.com/q/54721972/5260024 :)

Comment: cool question, eh? thanks for sharing. looks like B caught the issue already :D

Comment: I really like this solution - it shows mathematical understanding, and who doesn't like a decent use of recursion? :)

Answer (score 2):

Separate each 2 parametr.

```
function separator(str,sep) {
    var output = '';
    for (var i = str.length; i > 0; i-=2) {
        var ii = i-1;
        if(output) {
            output = str.charAt(ii-1)+str.charAt(ii)+sep+output;
        } else {
            output = str.charAt(ii-1)+str.charAt(ii);
        }            
    }
    return output;
}
console.log(separator('123456',':')); //Will return 12:34:56
```

Answer (score 2):

With ES6, you could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a stringed number as [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables) and [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) as mapping function.

```js
const getDigits = n => Array.from(n.toString(), Number);

console.log(getDigits(12345));
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```js
var number = 12354987;
console.log(String(number).split('').map(Number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Shadow Wizard , extended version by Orien

```
var num:Number = 1523;
var digits:Array = [];
var cnt:int = 0;
while (num > 0) {
    var mod:int = num % 10;
    digits.push(mod * Math.pow(10, cnt))

    num = Math.floor(num / 10);
    cnt++;
}
digits.reverse();
trace(digits);
```

output:1000,500,20,3

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach in order to get digits from a `number` would be to get a `string` from your `number`, split it into an `array` (of characters) and map each element back into a number.

For example:

```
var number = 123456;

var array = number.toString()
.split('')
.map(function(item, index) {
   return parseInt(item);
});

console.log(array); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you also need to sum all digits, you can append the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) method to the previous code:

```
var num = 123456;

var array = num.toString()
.split('')
.map(function(item, index) {
   return parseInt(item);
})
.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
}, 0);

console.log(array); // returns 21
```

---

As an alternative, with ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition), you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var number = 123456;
var array = number.toString().split('').map((item, index) => parseInt(item));
console.log(array); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you need to sum all digits, you can append the `reduce()` method to the previous code:

```
var num = 123456;

var result = num.toString()
.split('')
.map((item, index) => parseInt(item))
.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue, 0);

console.log(result); // returns 21
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this simple way of doing it.

**To split digits**

```
var N = 69;
var arr = N.toString().split('').map(Number)
// outputs [6,9]
console.log( arr );
```

**To add them together**

```
console.log(arr.reduce( (a,b) => a+b )); // 15
```

Answer (score 1):

And the easiest....  `num_string.split('').map(Number)`

Try below:

```js
console.log((''+123).split('').map(Number))
```

Answer (score 1):

To just split an integer into its individual digits in the same order, Regular Expression is what I used and prefer since it prevents the chance of loosing the identity of the numbers even after they have been converted into string.

The following line of code convert the integer into a string, uses regex to match any individual digit inside the string and return an array of those, after which that array is mapped to be converted back to numbers.

`const digitize = n => String(n).match(/\d/g).map(Number);`

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but a solution picking up bits and pieces. Perhaps, as I still learning, is that the functions does many things in the same one. Do not hesitate to correct me, please.

```
const totalSum = (num) => [...num + ' '].map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

So we take the parameter and convert it to and arr, adding empty spaces. We do such operation in every single element and push it into a new array with the map method. Once splited, we use reduce to sum all the elements and get the total.

As I said, don't hesitate to correct me or improve the function if you see something that I don't.

Almost forgot, just in case:

```
const totalSum = (num) => ( num === 0 || num < 0) ? 'I need a positive number' : [...num + ' '].map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

If negatives numbers or just plain zero go down as parameters. Happy coding to us all.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer to introduce the use of unshift which is a modern solution. With `push`, you add to the end of an array while unshift adds to the beginning. This makes the mathematical approach more powerful as you won't need to reverse anymore.

```js
let num = 278;
let digits = [];
while (num > 0) {
    digits.unshift(num % 10);
    num = parseInt(num / 10);
}
console.log(digits);
```

Answer (score 1):

And as a one liner.

```js
console.log(BigInt(1e200).toString().split('').reduce((pv, v) => Number(v) + pv, 0));
```

Comment: Breaks on large numbers, try out `1e200.toString().split("")`. That results in `[ "1", "e", "+", "2", "0", "0" ]`

Comment: There, large numbers 

Comment: Hehe, very smooth. Have my upvote!

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 111,
 separateDigits = num.toString().split(""), i, l = separateDigits.length;

for( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
someObject.someMethod( +separateDigits[i] );
}
```

Comment: Breaks on large numbers, try out `1e200.toString().split("")`. That results in `[ "1", "e", "+", "2", "0", "0" ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  var num = 99;

  num=num.toString().split("").map(value=>parseInt(value,10)); //output [9,9]
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Breaks on large numbers, try out `1e200.toString().split("")`. That results in `[ "1", "e", "+", "2", "0", "0" ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
function iterateNumber(N, f) {
    let n = N;
    var length = Math.log(n) * Math.LOG10E + 1 | 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const pow = Math.pow(10, length - i - 1)
        let c = (n - (n % pow)) / pow
        f(c, i)
        n %= pow
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. Currently, this is just a block of code that doesn't include any comments or help for people trying to learn the concept.

Answer (score 0):

`('' + 123456789).split('').map( x => +x ).reduce( (a,b) => a+b ) === 45`

true

or without map

`('' + 123456789).split('').reduce( (a,b) => (+a)+(+b) ) === 45`

true

Comment: The original question was about splitting the digits and adding them together

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in single line, seperate each digits than add them together :

```
var may = 12987;
var sep = (""+may).split("").map(n=>+n).reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
```

Comment: This too breaks with large numbers, try running `(""+2e200).split("")`. That will result in `[ "2", "e", "+", "2", "0", "0" ]`

Answer (score 0):

This is my short solution.. with sum of number

```
    function sum (num) {
    let sNumber = num
        .toString()
        .split('')
        .reduce((el1, el2) => {
            return Number(el1) + Number(el2)
        }, 0)
        return sNumber
     }
```

> console.log(sum(123))
>  
>   console.log(sum(456))

Comment: Breaks on large numbers, try out `1e200.toString().split("")`. That results in `[ "1", "e", "+", "2", "0", "0" ]`

Answer (score 0):

javascript has a function for it and you can use it easily.

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number));
```

for example :

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(2334325443534));
==> 2,334,325,443,534
```

Comment: Very worthwhile addition, but that doesn't really split it into individual digits.