# how to find the last digit of an integer using num.toString and str.split?

Tags: javascript

```
var num=1234
```

My answer should be 4 how do i do that?
I tried using "split" and "toString" but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I separate an integer into separate digits in an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914216/how-do-i-separate-an-integer-into-separate-digits-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use toString and split? Because the most efficient way is `num % 10`

Comment: thnks it works so i do num%10 and it gives me the last digit

Comment: but it doesnt work on huge numbers i  need it to work on any number

Answer (score 1):

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/jazokaw/2/edit?js,console)

```
var lastNum = num.toString().split('').pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var num = 1234;
var stringNum = num.toString();
var arrayNum = stringNum.split("");
var lastNumber = arrayNum[arrayNum.length-1];
```

Comment: <script>
function div (num)
{
function div (num)
{
var nums = num;
var stringNum = num.toString();
var arrayNum = stringNum.split("");
var lastNumber = arrayNum[arrayNum.length-1];
return lastNumber;
}

document.write (div(5555555555555555555555557))
</script>

Comment: "My answer should be 4 how do i do that? I tried using "split" and "toString" but I don't know how to use it." that is what he want