# How to give javascript find() method an argument to search?

Tags: javascript, find

I am trying to figure out a way to do search while iterating an array. I came across [`find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example).

Here is the example given:

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); 
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

I need find a dynamic fruit name, but I can't figure out how to do it. In short, I am trying to do something like:

```
function findCherries(fruit, fruitName) { 
    return fruit.name === fruitName;
};

inventory.find(findCherries('cherries'))
//"true is not a function"
```

Is there a way to give `find()` an argument and find a match base on that argument? If not, what method allows me to search an array of object dynamically?

Comment: Search for / read Eloquent JavaScript. The "problem" with the second form is the code eagerly evaluates the function call when it *should* pass a function-object; this can be solved easily with closures.

Comment: Ah, I see! "cherries" is not a function, that's why it didn't work. After reading the comments below, it makes sense to have a callback argument with the dynamic argument stubbed in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a closure (your function must return a function) like this:

```
function findFruitByName(name) {
    return function(fruit) {
        return fruit.name === name;
    }
}

inventory.find(findFruitByName('cherries'))
// {name: "cherries", quantity: 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
// find one
function findFruitByName(name, inventoy) {
  return inventory.find(function(item) {
    return item.name === name;
  });
}

// find all
function findFruitsByName(name, inventory) {
  return inventory.filter(function(item) {
    return item.name === name;
  });
}


let inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 88}
];

console.log('One', findFruitByName('cherries', inventory));
console.log('All', findFruitsByName('cherries', inventory));
```

Answer (score 2):

While a closure is the standard-approach, you could also supply the `thisArg` to [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control) and write:

```js
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findFruit(fruit) {
    return fruit.name == this;
};

console.log(inventory.find(findFruit, 'cherries'));
```

I don't recommend this approach here as it is a) less obvious and b) `this` is an `Object` and needs to be coerced into a primitive `string` either by non strict equality `==` or directly converting to `String(this)`, but it [can definitely come in handy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794370/1647737).

Comment: This is interesting approach compared to other answers. Thanks for sharing the trick!

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to give find() an argument and find a match base on that argument?*

Yes. Your first code sample already does that: the argument you are using is a function that looks for cherries.

The argument passed to `.find()` has to be a function that knows how to do the comparison you want. This comparison function can be defined anonymously right at the point where you need it:

```
let result = inventory.find(function(item) {
  return item.name === "cherries";
});
```

And you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to make the code significantly shorter:

```
let result = inventory.find(item => item.name === "cherries");
```

So if the value you are looking for is in some other variable:

```
let fruit = "cherries";
let result = inventory.find(item => item.name === fruit);
// OR
let result = inventory.find(function(item) {
  return item.name === fruit;
});
```

(Note that arrow functions aren't supported by IE, but neither is the `.find() method, so...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `thisArg` of the `find` method as argument, like in the code bellow (I used `filter`, you can use `find` as well)

```js
var myFind = function(el) {
  return (el.indexOf(this) !== -1); // check if 'el' string contains an 'arg' substring
};

console.log(["abc", "123", "xya", "xyz"]
            .filter(myFind, "a"));         // the argument is "a"
//output: ["abc", "xya"]
```