# AWS lambda function to speak number as digit in alexa

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have tried to use **say-as interpret-as** to make Alexa speak number in digits

Example - 9822 must not read in words instead '9,8,2,2'

One of the two ways I have tried is as follows:

```
this.emit(':tell',"Hi "+clientname+" your "+theIntentConfirmationStatus+" ticket is sent to "+ "<say-as interpret-as='digits'>" + clientno + "</say-as>",'backup');
```

The other one is this:

```
this.response.speak("Hi "+clientname+" your "+theIntentConfirmationStatus+" ticket is sent to "+ "<say-as interpret-as='digits'>" + clientno + "</say-as>");
```

Both are not working but working on a separate fresh function.

Answer (score 5):

Actually your code SHOULD work.
Maybe you can try in test simulator and send us the code your script produces? Or the logs?

I've tried the following:

```
   <speak>
        1. The numbers are: <say-as interpret-as="digits">5498</say-as>.
        2. The numbers are: <say-as interpret-as="spell-out">5498</say-as>.
        3. The numbers are: <say-as interpret-as="characters">5498</say-as>.
        4. The numbers are: <prosody rate="x-slow"><say-as interpret-as="digits">5498</say-as></prosody>.
        5. The number is: 5498.
    </speak>
```

Digits, Spell-out and Characters all have the effect you want.
If you want to Alexa to say it extra slow, use the prosody in #4.

Try using examples #2 or #3, maybe this works out?
Otherwise the example from Amod will work too.

Comment: Yes actually today since morning something is wrong with alexa I am not able to build module some global problem has occured I dont yet please see this post ( https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/107286/dialog-model-is-invalid.html)  I dont know this post was posted today in morning itself from someone and amazon have responded to it. My lambda function is also behaving absurd like I exluded digits and added telephone it worked but my twilio api called skipped without any error

Comment: I will post you my nodejs script and logs once can you share your personal id

Comment: Could you resolve your problem? What do you mean by "personal id"

Comment: your gmail so that I can send you my script and logs

Answer (score 0):

You can split number into individual digits using sample function ( please test it for your possible inputs-its not tested for all input). You can search for similar function on stackoverflow

```
function getNumber(tablenumber) {
    var number = (""+tablenumber).split("");
    var arrayLength = number.length;
    var tmp =" ";
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

        var tmp = tmp + myStringArray[i] + ", <break time=\"0.4s\"/> ";
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

In your main function... call this

```
var finalresult = getNumber(clientno);
this.emit(':tell',"Hi "+clientname+" your "+theIntentConfirmationStatus+" ticket is sent to "+  finalresult ,'backup');
```

Comment: please see my comment in nightflash's answer because its important to know

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Yep, nightflash's answer is great. 
You could also break the numbers up yourself if you need other formatting, such as emphasizing particular digits, add pauses, etc. You would need to use your Lambda code to convert the numeric string to multiple digits separated by spaces and any other formatting you need.

Here's an example based on the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784620/javascript-number-split-into-individual-digits):

```
var inputNumber = 12354987;
var output = '';
var sNumber = inputNumber.toString();

for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    // just adding spaces here, but could be SSML attributes, etc.
    output = output + sNumber.charAt(i) + ' ';
}

console.log(output);
```

This code could be refactored and done many other ways, but I think this is about the easiest to understand.

Comment: please see my comment in nightflash's answer because its important to know