# JS spread operator (...) and implicit conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I want to understand the logic behind this snippet of code I found on this site: `[...num+''].map(n=>+n) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
I would've asked in a comment on the original answer, but I don't have enough rep... yet.

I was working on a coding challenge on [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/dashboard) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48122867/11375798) from another question on this site worked really well, and was really concise, but I'm relatively new to JavaScript, and would like some clarification on why this worked.

The [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48122867/11375798) basically said that this function returns a digits in a number as an array of strings:

```
let num = 12345;

[...num+''] //["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

and that this little addition converted the strings back to integers:

```
[...num+''].map(n=>+n) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I would just google this on my own, but I don't know what any of these syntaxes are actually called...

Comment: `num + ''` converts a number into a string; `...` is spread syntax used to turn iterable values into comma separated elements. `n => +n` is an arrow function, the longer version is `n => { return +n; }`. `+n` is a shortcut to turn a string into a number.

Comment: @ChrisG so `num+''` would work for any number and `+n` would work for any string made of digits?

Comment: Basically yes; `+"a"` will evaluate to `NaN`.

Comment: @Skouzini `anyVar+''` will work for any datatype and will implicitly convert to string. `+anyVar` will convert any type to a number.

Comment: @ChrisG @VLAZ okay, that makes sense. Thank you! So would that mini function need to be assigned to a variable, or would it alter the variable `num`?

Comment: You need to assign it to something. The only operators that modify variables are auto-increment and assignments.